# what exactly happens when new operator is called for array and object?

Tags: java, arrays

I may be wrong but from what I understand when creating an object in java by:

```
Class object = new Class;
```

the `new Class` create new object of Class type which is then applied to `"object"` reference

so when u create array of objects by:

```
Class[] objects = new Class[10];
```

does it mean `new Class[10]` creates 10 objects of Class type wich are then applied to `objects` reference or just a memory for size of 10 objects of Class type is reserved and you need to create certain objects later

Comment: it will create 10 blocks all of the size of Class object. Then you will create the object in this place

Comment: you forget () is not scala xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later is correct `new Class[10]` will create a placeholder for 10 objects in memory and you need to put objects explicitly in them.

Comment: so why new Class actually create object instead of placeholder for 1 object in memory or am I wrong understanding it?

Comment: your understanding is correct and That is the difference between an object and object[]

Comment: thx 1 more thing; from souce: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator new[]/ (I know it is C++ but it should be similar) it says is creates memory for number of objects "and if this is successful, it then automatically initializes or constructs every object in the array (if needed)" so when is "if needed" case

Comment: I read through it. it is talking about the three kind of usage for new[] operator i.e. throwing allocation, no throw allocation and placement. In Java there is only one scenarios in which objects are also created and assigned to array. that happens by doing `String[] myarr = new[]{"one","two"};` this will create array and assign objects as well

Answer (score 0):

`new Class[10]` does create memory for 10 placeholders. It does not allocate the memory for individual entries.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:
    bool [] booleanArray;
    FileInfo [] files;

```
booleanArray = new bool[10];
files = new FileInfo[10];
```

Here, the booleanArray is an array of the value type System.Boolean, while the files array is an array of a reference type, System.IO.FileInfo. The following figure shows a depiction of the CLR-managed heap after these four lines of code have executed.

[image]

Eventhough this is a C# example. This is similar to what we have in Java.

Answer (score 0):

**objects** will be a pointer to an array of pointers. These pointers will point to objects of type Class. No memory is allocated for anybody but the actual pointers. So **new Class[10]** creates 10 pointers, which are referenced by **objects**.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array of objects is similar to create variables i.e. the code 
`Class[] objects = new Class[10];` can be interpreted as

```
Class object1;
Class object2;
...
```

for using them or calling function and accessing variables we have to call the constructor ie.

```
object1 = new Class();
object2 = new Class();
```

So `Class[] objects  = new Class[10];` is creating 10 references of Class and no memory allocation has been done for the objects. For doing that we have to call the constructor for them like `object[0] = new Class();`
Now the objects have been created memory has been allocated and we can use them.
Also if after creation of array of objects without calling constructor we use them like object[0].somefunction() it will show null pointer exception.